# Error in scanf()

Tags: c, input, multidimensional-array, scanf

first of all, I've got a logical error in my code. Well, this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long i,j,t;
    scanf("%ld",&t);
    long n[t],d[t][t];
    for(i = 0; i < t;i++){
        scanf("%ld",&n[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < n[i] ;j++){
            scanf("%ld",&d[j][i]);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < t;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n[i] ;j++){
            printf("%ld ",d[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I input the data

```
2
4
25 20 30 90
3
45 50 55
```

And the result is

```
25 20 30 90
45 50 55
```

Well, that's what I expected. However, when the input become like this

```
3
5
12 67 89 34 56
6
34 56 78 90 12 34
7
12 34 89 23 56 78 89
```

The result become like this

```
12 34 89 23 56 78 89
12 67 89 34 56 4206692 7 2293472 1982002386 16 3 2293344 2293408 0 2293552 0 0 4
198585 8918456 1982106837 1982010910 8918456 2293640 0 0 1985286516 2009576437 0
 0 2293664 2009323341 2293740 2147348480 0
34 56 78 90 12 34 4199405 1982595752 8 12 2293424 2 2 1982356412 2147348480 2293
608 2147348480 1 -1 297753669 1982010784 1982015505 4199044 0 0 2147348480 21473
48480 0 0 0 7273647 2009576392 0 0 0 1 0 20 52 0 0 438759246 736 -214797894 1420
 760826203 2272 852421325 3108 944791496 4028 -1322777276 4988 9 1 1 1204 7168 4
 2 152 11832 7 1 40 12316 1682469715 1 140 44 0 0 0 2 0 7209065 5701724 6029427

12 34 89 23 56 78 89
```

Well, the simple question, why the output become like the above?? When I input above 2, the same result will be happened. Any possible answers and links if you don't mind it?? Thanks

Comment: I think it may help to clarify what you are trying to accomplish here. Do you want to use a 2d array for a particular reason? Do you want to have rows of varying length? What is the goal? Do you want to be able to instantly access an element at row 5 position 3? More details will help us figure out a good solution.

Comment: At first example, you declare `d` as `long[2][2]`, and you fill it with 4 data. You are going out of program memory allocation. That's very basic in C

Answer (score 1):

You are writing outside your 2D array in many cases, sometimes you don't get errors, but that's just by chance.

You determine the size of the 2D array by the number of arrays to be inputted, but you also determine the size of the inner arrays at the same time:

```
scanf("%ld",&t);
long n[t],d[t][t];
```

So for example, let's take the first example:

```
2              >> create array n[2], and array d[2][2]
4              >> number of values to d[0]
25 20 30 90    >> d[0][1] = 25 d[0][2] = 20 you access d[0][3] and d[0][4] but you are not allowed to do that.
3              >> number of values to d[1]
45 50 55       >> d[1][0] = 45 d[1][1] = 50 you access d[1][2] but you are not allowed to do that
```

Comment: so, should I change the dimension of array?? or any solution to prevent the logical error??

Comment: Don't use such a 2D array, You should probably use dynaic allocations, and for each row, after you get its size, allocate the appropriate memory.

Comment: Well if you want to keep the size t x t then make sure that every number you enter specifying dimensions is less than t. You could change for(j = 0; j < n[i] ;j++) to for(j = 0; j < n[i] && j < t ;j++) for example.

Comment: you mean, like linked list or tree??

Answer (score 0):

You build a matrix with size `t*t`, then fill in rows with more or less elements.

If you fill a row with too few elements, the rest remain uninitialized, and you get strange numbers. It's OK in your case, because you don't print these elements.

If you fill a row with too many elements, the excess overlaps into the next row. It may also exceed the whole matrix and corrupt your stack.
I guess this is what's going on - your `n` array is overrun, and your code goes crazy.

Comment: hmm, no, the result I expected is like the first example.

Comment: I understand what you expected, but when writing outside an array, you don't get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use `malloc`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long i,j,t;
    printf("Rows : ");
    scanf("%ld",&t);
    long *n;
    long **d;
    n = (long* )malloc(sizeof(long) * t); // add malloc
    d = (long** )malloc(sizeof(long *) * t); // add malloc

    for(i = 0; i < t;i++){
        printf("Column : ");
        scanf("%ld",&n[i]);
        d[i] = (long* )malloc(sizeof(long) * n[i]); //add malloc
        if(d[i] == NULL)
        printf("ERROR\n");

        for(j = 0; j < n[i] ;j++){
            scanf("%ld", &d[i][j]); // change from &d[j][i]
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < t;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n[i] ;j++){
            printf("%ld ",d[i][j]); // change from d[j][i]
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Well, the simple question, why the output become like the above?? When
>   I input above 2, the same result will be happened. Any possible
>   answers and links if you don't mind it?? Thanks

1. because you allocate less memory than used.
2. `scanf("%ld", &d[j][i]);` you have to exchange the "i" and "j".